# How can I check session in base.html.twig in symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How can I check session in base.html.twig in symfony4? Or how can I pass session variable in base.html.twig or how can I pass any variable in base.html.twig in symfony4?

I tried this in config/packages/twig.yaml:

```
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    globals:
        ga_tracking: app.session
```

then {{ dump(ga_tracking) }} in base.html.twig, but it returns empty.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `app.session`.

As documented here:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/app_variable.html

As for injecting your own, global, variables, check this bit here:
https://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: I tried {{ dump(app.session) }} in base.html.twig, but it returns empty.

Comment: I also tried  globals:
        ga_tracking: app.session in twig.yaml, and then {{ dump(ga_tracking) }} in base.html.twig but it returns empty.

Comment: it returns null if there is no active session

Comment: I tried after login , still app.session is empty. what is active session?

Comment: What is the difference of your `base.html.twig` template compared to `index.html.twig`?